# How to remove old form to stop double-submission

Tags: javascript, django

I am using AJAX to submit a form from a modal window. If the form is submitted with errors the server will send back a new form. The container holding the old form is then removed and the new form, with validation errors, is set in it's place.

The issue is that, for some reason, it submits 2 forms at the same exact time *after the validation errors are fixed*. It is as-if the old form does not get removed?

It does not happen when I use the `onclick=functionCall()` syntax but rather when I use the `$('form').on('submit', e => {` syntax. I am trying to use the latter as I was told the onX events are now considered bad practice.

Any help on understanding what is happening and how to fix it would be useful.

**Form:**

```
    // Submit Form
$('form').on('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let data = new FormData($(e.target).get(0));
    const btn = $(e.target).find('button:submit')
    const container = document.getElementById('formFields')
    $.ajax({
        url         : e.target.action,
        data        : data,
        type        : 'POST',
        headers     : {"X-CSRFToken": token},
        enctype     : 'multipart/form-data',
        processData : false,
        contentType : false,
        success     : function (data) {
            btn.toggleClass('btn-warning btn-secondary').prop('disabled', true)
        },
        error       : function (data) {
            container.innerHTML = loadingSpinner;
            $(container).empty();
            $(container).html(data['responseJSON']['table']).fadeIn('slow');
        },
    });
});
```

**View:**

```
@login_required
def load_add_memo_form(request, pk=None):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.is_ajax():
        memo_form = MemoForm(
            data=request.POST,
            files=request.FILES,
            company=request.tenant)
        memo_form.instance.sender = request.user
        if pk:
            memo = get_object_or_404(Memo, pk=pk)
            memo_form = Memo(
                data=request.POST,
                files=request.FILES,
                company=request.tenant,
                instance=memo)
        if memo_form.is_valid():
            if request.user.role.supervisor is None or request.user is memo_form.sender:
                memo_form.save()
                reason_for_notification = 'memo to view'
                notifier = SendNotifications(request, reason_for_notification, memo_form)
                notifier.send_notifications()
                return JsonResponse({'success': True})
        else:
            data = {'table': render_to_string('memos/components/add_memo_form.html', context={'form': memo_form})}
            return JsonResponse(data, status=400)
    else:
        memo_form = MemoForm(company=request.tenant)
        if pk:
            memo = get_object_or_404(Memo, pk=pk)
            memo_form = MemoForm(company=request.tenant, instance=memo)
        context = {'form': memo_form}
        template = 'memos/components/add_memo_form.html'
        return render(request, template, context)
```

And obvious the form is just templating language...

Comment: Just reset the form once the person clicks it and you have collected all the data you need

Comment: I am doing that, aren't I?

Comment: No, You are not doing that. Do it right after making the ajax call.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would you mind giving an example? I am not understanding correctly. When the form returns errors I then call `.empty()` and put the new form in there. What should I be doing? Thanks!

Comment: What I want to say is when you have specified your `$.ajax` call, not when it succeeded or when it got an error. I mean right after you call, it you will clear the form or reload the page.